# How to get missing previous quarter data

Tags: excel, powerbi

I'm having two different tables Finance and Budgets. There is a relationship between two tables.

Finance Table:

| As of Date | Property Id | YTD Revenue | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/31/21 | 1 | $5,000 | 1 |
| 6/30/21 | 1 | $6,000 | 2 |
| 3/31/21 | 2 | $7,000 | 1 |
| 6/30/21 | 2 | $8,000 | 2 |

Budgets:

| As of Date | Property Id | Budget Revenue | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/31/21 | 1 | $10,000 | 1 |
| 6/30/21 | 1 | $10,000 | 2 |
| 3/31/21 | 2 | $11,000 | 1 |

The business doesn't want to enter the data if the Budget Revenue is same as the last quarter.

There is a quarter slicer on the page and I'm using Finance[Quarter]. Let's say I'm selecting 2nd quarter and there is no quarter 2 data for the property id 2 on the Budgets table and in this case we have to show Budget Revenue from last quarter i.e 3/31/2021($11,000).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Budget` table.

- Combine the two tables using `JoinKind.FullOuter` with all the columns except Revenue as the key
- Expand the `Budget Revenue` column of the resultant table
- `Fill Down` the `Budget Revenue` column
- delete the unneeded columns and re-order the columns

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(
                Revenue, {"As of Date", "Property Id", "Quarter"}, 
                Budget, {"As of Date", "Property Id", "Quarter"}, "Budget", 
                JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded Budget" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Budget", {"Budget Revenue"}, {"Budget Revenue"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Expanded Budget",{"Budget Revenue"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"YTD Revenue"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"As of Date", "Budget Revenue", "Quarter"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response Ron. I'm having one more question.

Comment: Thank you for the response Ron. I'm having one more question. I don't have quarter 3 data in the budgets table. What if I want 3rd quarter data in the budgets table. I do have quarter 3 data in Finance table.As of Date Property Id YTD Revenue Quarter 
3/31/21 1 $5,000  1
6/30/21 1 $6,000  2
3/31/21 2 $7,000  1
6/30/21 2 $8,000  2
9/30/21 2 $9,000  3

Comment: @Nitin that is exactly what this does. However, I mistakenly named your Finance table the Revenue table. So just substitute that in the code.

Comment: Thank you. I followed all the steps and it's working. But I got stuck at the last step to fill down the values.  7111
6407
4461
73925
11904
null
null
null
null
null I would like to duplicate the same values.(7111,6407,4461,73925,11904). Is there any way around to do it. Thank you

Comment: @Nitin The code I posted obviously works with the data you supplied.  What you post in your comment does not clarify, for me, the problem you are having. I'll guess that your supplied data is not truly representative, requiring some changes in the algorithm. Or possibly when you changed the code to fit in with your real data, you made some errors.